# DIY solar tracking system without any sensors

Tags: solar-cell, light-sensor

I'm building a tracking system for my university project. We will use two solar panels, one without tracking system and other one with tracking system and see the results if it's worth it or not.

But I got a idea, if I know right tracking system's goal is get many power as possible. So instead of using sensors to measure solar radiation density, can I use a voltmeter to measure solar panel's output and use the code of little bit try and error?

Like code change the angle little bit (every five minute) and if it has increased the output keep the change until the maximum ratio is achieved.

I know code will be almost impossible to write but I was always interested in machine learning systems and it seemed great way to start.

Solar panels are 50*40cm and output is 12-19 V 30-60 W (values not certain because we didn't decide panels yet).

Comment: The purpose of comments is to request clarification or point out errors so that the question can be improved. They are not for extended discussion, nor are they the place to write answers. This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100418/discussion-on-question-by-mordecai-diy-solar-tracking-system-without-any-sensors).  Any conclusions reached should be edited back into the question and/or any answer(s).

Answer (score -1):

It could be done without any sensor.

The first way is knowing the exact position in the Earth and in what direction the panel are looking, and depending of the time and day of the year the panel can be moved in different angles depending the hour and date.

Other way is looking for the maximum power point of the solar panel in the current place, and every time you move the solar panel. During all the search of the maximum power point in every place you are wasting some of the power of the power you are receiving from the Sun and in the motors moving the panel as well.

Also, this isn't a topic to use a machine learning. Surely the software needed in an Arduino board to manage a project like this wouldn't have more than 100 ~ 150 lines of code.

PS:
Maximum power point tracking are used to find the right amount of voltage and current a solar panel can give to achieve the maximum power delivery: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_point_tracking

Comment: How can you what direction the panel is looking without a sensor? How can you find the maximum power point if you don't have sensors to tell you how much power is provided?

Comment: You can use arduino to calculate power but panel's looking direction and position of earth have to use extra sensors. I'm waiting for my parts so I can test it and clarify the answer.